# Разместить окно приложения по заданным координатам

Tags: python, gui

Есть окно определенного приложения, хочу с помощью питона управлять расположением окна на экране. Т.е. задавать координаты, и окно будет перемещено согласно координатам. Как это можно сделать ?

Comment: окно вашему приложению принадлежит или чужое?

Answer (score 5):

Напрямую - никак. Нужно искать соответствующие API операционной системы и графической оболочки и биндинги для них к Python. Более того - их готовых может и не оказаться. Что делать? Готовить велосипед самому. Варианты вызова Win32API описаны, например, [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025029/how-to-use-win32-apis-with-python). Для X11 примеры посмотрите [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676434/x11-how-to-raise-another-applications-window-using-python)

Еще нужно учесть, что просто так нормальная графическая среда не даст управлять *чужими* окнами - ишь чего захотели. Это как минимум серьезная дыра безопасности.

*чужими* - подразумеваю: созданными не Вашим конкретным приложением. В это входят и окна приложений, запущенных другими пользователями в т.ч.

Comment: Или писать быблиотеку на Cи.